# Unable to get IP address of Raspberry pi to give remote desktop connection

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, putty, dynamic-ip

I am trying to give my Raspberry pi 3 B+ remote access using my windows laptop. I have connected raspberry using a ethernet cable and gave wifi connection to laptop. Then I tried making a bridge connection between both of them. To get the IP address of raspberry I scanned using advanced ip scanner. But from the results I got, I am not able to identify my raspberry pi IP.

`On P                 192.168.1.100       Intel Corporate`
`On P                 192.168.70.1        VMware, Inc.`  
`On 192.168.70.254    192.168.70.254      VMware, Inc.`  
`On P                 192.168.100.1       VMware, Inc.`  
`On 192.168.100.254   192.168.100.254     VMware, Inc.`

How can I find IP address of my raspberry pi? When researching about this I saw in a article raspberry buster has dynamic IP address and need to use different methods to find IP.is this true? If so what are those methods?

I am totally new to this and any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: "*I have connected raspberry using a ethernet cable and gave wifi connection to laptop*" - do you connected to the laptop with and ethernet cable AND by WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but if you are using ICS the Pi will have internet access BUT you will not be able to access it from the laptop.

Connect the Pi to your router.

The only option is to turn your laptop into a router which is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

For first trials - connect computer AND raspberry pi via ethernet if you can. You will be sure you are in one network ;)

Comment: This is only true if you direct connect the Raspi with an ethernet cable to the computer.